# When dismiss child parent VC reloads completely

Tags: ios, swift

I have so strange issue. I have parent VC named `NewAdCreationViewController` it presents modally child VC named `CollectionPicturesViewController`. 
In child VC I have link to the parent VC.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == picturesCollectionVCSegueName {

        let collectionController = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).viewControllers.first as! CollectionPicturesViewController
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? PicturesCollectionTableViewCell
        guard cell != nil else{ return }
        collectionController.picturesArray = cell!.itemPictures
        collectionController.parentVC = self // this is link!
    }
}
```

In child VC I present another VC for picking photos - `DKImagePickerController`(pod). After picking all my photos appears in collectionView in child VC, and when I tap "Save" I want to pass all that data to parent VC and dismiss child,

```
    @objc func savePictures(){
    self.parentVC.pictures = self.picturesArray
    self.parentVC.tableView.reloadData()

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but after I dismiss it my parent reloads completely and starts from `viewDidLoad`. It presents completely new VC(I've checked in console, it has another address in memory). I really don't know why is that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show more info! How is `parentVC` defined? What kind of segue is this? Can you show a diagram of how these view controllers are related? I'm sure we can sort this out easily if you can just explain it more fully. Thanks.

Comment: @matt I've added some screenshots. `parentVC` is just property in `NewAdCreationViewController `

Comment: 2 things I would suggest. One is using `weak self` when assigning the parentVC to a variable on the child. The other is to make sure you don't have some funky code in `ViewDidAppear` or some such simpler explanation.

Comment: Also, just saw your screenshot, Your should probably be pushing the child VC onto the navigation controller you already have instead of instantiating a new one.

Comment: @NSGangster yes, I can do it, but I need to present it modally, and because of that I need navigationBar with BarButtons and that's why I've created new navigationController

Comment: You could for sure do a "pop" onto the navigation controller but change the transition style to behave like a modal. That way you get functionality of nav controller but with the transition of modal. NavigationControllers are imo the "best" way to achieve what your after with less headache. But I'm not saying it is not possible with your current setup. You just tend to run into unexpected consequences like the one you find yourself in currently.

Comment: I'm thinking there is some unexpected behavior occurring because of a strong reference cycle. Instead of assigning the parentVC variable. You could access your navigational hierarchy of childVC and grab the parentVC from there. That way it won't be referenced outside of the scope of the function.         `if let parentVC = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? CollectionPicturesViewController {}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController reloads view after its dismissed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682844/uiimagepickercontroller-reloads-view-after-its-dismissed)

Comment: I agree that you probably don't need to use modal presentation and another navigation controller, but it should work. You should check that you haven't linked a segue to the action of your "save" button. I would also suggest you use an unwind segue rather than calling dismiss

Comment: Thank you all guys! I've found solution. You can see it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On highlighted segue I've changed presentation to `Over full screen`. And it works perfectly without reloads!
[image]